# ReactDom.Render() method should have return statement

Tags: reactjs

I am encountering this issue below:

```
Line 5:  Your render method should have return statement  react/require-render-return
```

I was under the assumption that the ReactDom.render() returns null on stateless components.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Match, Miss } from 'react-router';
import SearchBar from './components/SearchBar.js'


const Root = () => {
    return(
        <div className="searchbar"> <SearchBar/> </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Root />, document.querySelector('#searchbar')
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: are you using `eslint` ?

Comment: `const Root = () =>  <div className="searchbar"> <SearchBar/> </div>;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no space between `return` and `(`

```
const Root = () => {
        return (
            <div className="searchbar"> <SearchBar/> </div>
        )
    }
```

(or)

```
const Root = () => <div className="searchbar"> <SearchBar/> </div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Root component is fine. The problem is probably with your SearchBar component which you haven't posted...

(there should be space between the 'return' and the '(' but it doesn't seem to cause the error).